# Dismiss angularstrap calendar when typing and show up when click input

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm having trouble to dismiss the calendar when typing date by hand and popup when its clicked again. Are there any other way I tried below that I can dismiss the calendar?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="datePicker.date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" bs-datepicker data-bs-show="datePicker.show">
```

I have my directive that blur the element, but i keep losing the focus on the input

```
element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
    scope.$apply(function (){
    element[0].blur();
    });
});
```

I tried to destroy the element `element.remove()`, but i have click twice to show up the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hated to do this, but it works... In your input, you need 2 functions, one is `ng-blur` and `ng-click`. So I set as false my default scope `data-bs-show="datePicker.show"``and then add validation on those 2 functions mentioned.

```
$scope.calendarShow = false;

$scope.clickCalendar = function(){
    if($scope.calendarShow){
        $scope.calendarShow = false
    } else{
        $scope.calendarShow =true
    }
}

$scope.blurCalendar = function(){
    $scope.calendarShow = false;
}
```

Edit: forgot to mention, use the keypress function and set scope to false